# SparkAction for yarn-cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

Using the Hortonworks HDP 2.3 preview sandbox (oozie:4.2.0.2.3.0.0-2130, spark:1.3 and Hadoop:2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2130), I am trying to invoke the oozie spark action using "yarn-cluster" as the master. The example provided in [Oozie Spark Action](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html) is for running the spark action on "local" master.

The same page also suggests to be able to run on Yarn, the spark assembly jar should be available to the spark action.

I have two questions

- How do we make the spark assembly jar available to Spark Action? Should I use the jar element in the oozie spark action?
- I get the following error when I submit the job without adding the assembly jar explicitly

  ```
  Using properties file: null
  Using properties file: null
  Parsed arguments:
     master                  yarn-master
     deployMode              cluster
     executorMemory          512m
     executorCores           null
     totalExecutorCores      null
     propertiesFile          null
     extraSparkProperties    Map()
     driverMemory            null
     driverCores             null
     driverExtraClassPath    null
     driverExtraLibraryPath  null
     driverExtraJavaOptions  null
     supervise               false
     queue                   null
     numExecutors            3
     files                   null
     pyFiles                 null
     archives                null
     mainClass               com.foo.bar.spark.examples.WordCountSparkJob
     primaryResource         hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/apps/foo/sandbox.hortonworks.com/1.201-SNAPSHOT/oozieapp/lib/abc-1.201-SNAPSHOT.jar
     name                    Spark Example
     childArgs               [inputpath=hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/bcp_examples/input/]
     jars                    null
     verbose                 true

  Default properties from null:
  Error: Could not load YARN classes. This copy of Spark may not have been compiled with YARN support.
  Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
  Intercepting System.exit(-1)
  Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [-1]
  ```

Appreciate any pointers on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The default sharelib distributed with Oozie in HDP2.3 for the spark action is not assembled for YARN.

If you've installed the spark via the hortonworks distro, then you can just replace the contents of the sharelib for the spark action with the installed version.

E.g. (as the oozie user)

```
hadoop fs -mv /user/oozie/share/lib/spark /user/oozie/share/lib/spark-bak
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/oozie/share/lib/spark
hadoop fs -put /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/* /user/oozie/share/lib/spark
hadoop fs -cp /user/oozie/share/lib/spark-bak/oozie* /user/oozie/share/lib/spark
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by class `org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client` can't be loaded. And it contains in spark-assembly jar, which can be find in the `/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/`. After you add this file into `hdfs://hd-host:port/user/oozie/share/lib/spark`, you have to restart oozie to make it valid immediately.