# Hortonworks Oozie Spark Action

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

Has anyone managed to successfully run a Spark action through Oozie in HDP?

I am running on HDP 2.3.2 with Oozie 4.2.0. The spark action is set to run in yarn-cluster mode. The spark job is a dummy one, with no input file.

I have first hit the error over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904316/sparkaction-for-yarn-cluster) and managed to bypass it by removing the following from the hdfs oozie spark lib folder (in my case: `/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151116201309/spark/`):

- tachyon-0.5.0.jar
- tachyon-client-0.5.0.jar (both because of [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-not-implemented-by-the-tfs-filesystem-implementation-when-starting-spark/25763) error)
- spark-core_2.10-1.1.0.jar
- spark-graphx_2.10-1.1.0.jar
- spark-streaming_2.10-1.1.0.jar

and added the following in the workflow lib folder:

- datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar
- datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar
- datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar
- spark-1.4.1.2.3.2.0-2950-yarn-shuffle.jar
- spark-assembly-1.4.1.2.3.2.0-2950-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar
- spark-examples-1.4.1.2.3.2.0-2950-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar

Now I land on the following error:

> Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], main() threw exception, Call From hdp4/10.10.1.84 to 0.0.0.0:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
>   java.net.ConnectException: Call From hdp4/10.10.1.84 to 0.0.0.0:8032 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

I mention that:

- both in job.properties file and in the yarn config file, the job tracker/resource manager port is set to 8032
- the application runned for ~20min (I ran it multiple times and observed this timing)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried

Comment: What version of HDP are you using? What have you tried, and what errors are you running into?

Comment: @PeterSmith I have added more info, thank you

Comment: @TonTorres I have added more info, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I performed to get SparkAction to work on HDP 2.3.4.

1. Backup the Oozie sharelib spark folder and delete all the jars inside except `oozie-sharelib-<spark-version>.jar`. In my case I simply renamed the spark folder to `spark-backup` and created a new `spark` folder, then copied the jar I mentioned.
2. Copy all of the jars from `$SPARK_HOME/lib` to the Oozie sharelib spark folder.
3. Restart Oozie
4. Changed yarn.resourcemanager.address to `<myhost>:8032` via Ambari
5. Restarted YARN

I had more or less the same problems before, so I posted this [question](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/7014/oozie-sparkaction-throwing-javalangnosuchmethoderr.html) on the Hortonworks Community, which is what helped me to finally get it working.

Comment: Instead of restarting the service, you can just "resync" the ShareLibs using the CLI - https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Update_system_sharelib

Comment: Thanks Samson, I didn't know that.